# Extension methods and class library's for importing HttpResponseException

Tags: c#, exception, httpresponse, class-library

I've got this extension method that check for some info in the request cookie and if this info I'm looking for is not in the cookie I go to the database.

All this is OK but when I built this extension I designed it in my MVC4 application, and now I am refactoring items to relative library's and I cannot seem to find a way to import or add a reference to my class library that would allow me to throw an HttpResponseException.

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

```
    namespace LinkedIn.Extensions
{
    public static class httprequest_linkedincontext
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Extension that creates a OAuthLinkedIn object by checking the cookie first, and if the cookie has no LinkedIn info or has expried then builds the LinkedIn OAuthLinkedIn from the database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request"></param>
        /// <param name="userName"></param>
        /// <returns>oAuthLinkedIn information</returns>
        public static oAuthLinkedIn GetLinkedInContext(this HttpRequestMessage request, string userName)
        {
            OAuthHelper helper = new OAuthHelper(request, userName, false);
            oAuthLinkedIn oauth = new oAuthLinkedIn(helper.Verify, helper.Token, helper.TokenSecret);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oauth.Token) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(oauth.TokenSecret))
            {
                throw new System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
            }
            return oauth;
        }
    }
}
```

Right now there is a little red squiggle line under Http in the System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException.

Comment: What's the error? Are you referencing the `System.Web.Http` assembly?

Comment: Yes, the design time error is telling me that there is no System.Web.Http namespace, and I cannot find it to important it from "Add A Reference"

Comment: Do you have the Web API as one of the Nuget packages for the project? I think `System.Web.Http` is part of the Web API so you'll need to have that available.

Comment: Are you sure your library is referencing the right version of the CLR? The target version of the CLR can influence which assemblies appear in "Add a Reference".

Comment: Targeting: .NET Framework 4.5